# Mapping a DTO to an Entity with Automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have an Entity Framework POCO with the following structure.

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I've created a Data Transfer Object for this entity to be used by my views.

```
public class EntityDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have the following mapping code in my Global.asax file.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entity, EntityDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<EntityDto, Entity>(); // not sure whether I need this as well?
```

Everything is working fine, I pass the DTO to my views OK and I can create a new instance of `Entity` from my `EntityDto` model. The problem arises when I try to edit my `Entity`; I'm aware this is down to AutoMapper losing the Entity Key that EF creates to track changes to the object, but having read through a few sources there doesn't seem to be a definitive solution. Here is the action I'm using to edit my entity.

```
public ActionResult EditEntity(EntityDto model)
{
    var entity = context.Entities.Single(e => e.Id == model.Id);
    entity = Mapper.Map<EntityDto, Entity>(model); // this loses the Entity Key stuff
    context.SaveChanges();

    return View(model);
}
```

Now, what do I do to solve this?  Can I:

1. Somehow tell AutoMapper to `.Ignore()` the Entity Key properties?
2. Get AutoMapper to copy out the Entity Key properties?
3. `.Attach()` my mapped `Entity` and set the state to modified?

Any help always appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> .Attach() my mapped Entity and set the state to modified?

```
public ActionResult EditEntity(EntityDto model)
{
    var entity = Mapper.Map<Entity>(model);
    context.Set<Entity>().Attach(entity); // (or context.Entity.Attach(entity);)
    context.Entry<Entity>(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
    return View(model);
}
```

Where is your context instantiated? You should do that in your EditEntity action imo.

```
public ActionResult EditEntity(EntityDto model)
{
    using(var context = new MyContext())
    {
        var entity = Mapper.Map<Entity>(model);
        context.Set<Entity>().Attach(entity); // (or context.Entity.Attach(entity);)
        context.Entry<Entity>(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, this has just worked. Give me a few moments to try in my actual project.

Comment: Glad I could alt-tab and copy paste.. I mean help you. :)

Comment: You shouldn't use EF entities directly inside the presentation layer, this is a classic example of how not to separate your concerns.

Comment: @user692942 completly agree with you there. 10 years ago, I did not have good coding practices. These days, I would wrap that logic in a data layer (probably in a repository patern) that never exposes the EF models to the presentation layer. However, the question was not about code structure but about how to use a incoming DTO object from the presentation layer and update an entity with it.

Comment: I would also probably avoid assuming a DTO object has all the properties of the data model. I would prefer to load the model from the database, then use automapper to update only the fields the DTO has a mapping for, then save the context. What I suggested is dangerous to refactoring / new feature. If you add a field in your data model / column in your database and forget to add it to your DTO / presentation layer (or is not applicable to that view), the code I posted would empty that column / set it to default value.

Answer (score 25):

Try passing entity as a second parameter to your mapping.

```
entity = Mapper.Map<EntityDto, Entity>(model, entity);
```

Otherwise, your entity instance is overwritten with a new instance, and you lose the entity created in the first line.

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried this, causes the same issue - basically AutoMapper says it cannot find a mapping config as when I've retrieved my `Entity` from the context, it's not just your average POCO anymore and so AutoMapper doesn't know what to do.

Comment: if there are other properties on Entity that you haven't listed, you may as well want to tell AutoMapper to ignore them:
  
  .ForMember(dest => dest.PropertyToIgnore, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue)

Comment: This is the issue, at the time I'm creating my AutoMapper mappings `Entity` is just a POCO, so doesn't contain any of the extra entity stuff that EF creates when retrieving, so I can't tell AutoMapper to ignore them.

Comment: well then entity returned on the first line is not of type Entity, hover over 'var' and see what type it is, and create a mapping for that type. Also, it's the second mapping <dto--> entity> you need, not the first one

Comment: Holy CRUD I did not know you could do this with Map. Amazing.

Comment: Wait, doesn't this mean that if the EntityDto is a subset of Entity (which it almost always is), then it will fail the Assert test?

Comment: @dark_ruby thank you very much , it solve my problem

Answer (score 4):

An alternative answer that doesn't require Automapper for the DTO to Entity conversion is using a DbEntry:

```
        var oldEntity = DbSet.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == updatedEntity.Id);
        var oldEntry = Context.Entry(oldEntity);

        oldEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedEntity);
```

You don't need any attach/state checking because you are getting the old entity first so it has change tracking attached to it. Also, the CurrentValues.SetValues can accept a different type, in this example updatedEntity is the DTO. Set Values documentation is explained as such:

> Sets the values of this dictionary by reading values out of the given object. The given object can be of any type. Any property on the object with a name that matches a property name in the dictionary and can be read will be read. Other properties will be ignored. This allows, for example, copying of properties from simple Data Transfer Objects (DTOs).

So seems like it already can perform in an automapper-esque way.

Comment: This totally worked for me. The Mapper.Map(model, entity) solution didn't work for me, because when you have a nested entity, which you update (so your property references a different (ALREADY tracked) entity now), the automapper solution will "overwrite" the previously referenced entity, and the changetracker will complain that it's already tracking an entity with that identifier.

Comment: This is what happens when your EF bleeds into the presentation layer.