# Can AutoMapper map to an attached entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

For my update operations, my controller action does something like this:

```
    public Task<IHttpActionResult> Update(int id, CustomerTypeDto customerTypeDto)
    {
        var entity = customerTypeService.Get(id);

        entity.Number = customerTypeDto.Number;
        entity.Description = customerTypeDto.Description;

        entity = customerTypeService.Save(entity);

        return Ok<CustomerTypeDto>(Mapper.Map<CustomerTypeDto>(entity));
    }
```

This is a simple example with a simple entity consisting of 2 properties. Most of my entities are complex entities having tons of properties and deep relationships.

I need to load the entity from the DB first so that it starts being tracked by the context. I set the properties and then save the updated entity back into the DB. The repository's update method looks like this:

```
    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = dataContext.GetEntry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entity);
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
```

Doing the above, EF correctly creates and Update SQL statement consisting of only the changes properties.

With Automapper, is it possible to map the dto class to the model after it was loaded from db, so that changes can be tracked when the mapping occurs?

Instead of doing:

```
entity.Number = customerTypeDto.Number;
entity.Description = customerTypeDto.Description;
```

Is it possible to do:

```
entity = Mapper.Map(customerTypeDto, entity);
```

If this is not possible, what other alternatives are there apart from setting individual properties? Maybe using [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) or this [Delta implemenation](https://gist.github.com/benfoster/4488755)?

Comment: I don't see any problem with this code. Can you elaborate more on this 'so that changes can be tracked when the mapping occurs' ?

Comment: "If you use AutoMapper in your DAL however, you are almost certainly returning more data than you need from the database, as the mapping will not occur until AFTER the original query has executed and the data has been returned." taken from http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/stop-using-automapper-in-your-data-access-code

Comment: Your issue is that EF loses the tracking, to solve this use Attach() ... This should give you your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156437/mapping-a-dto-to-an-entity-with-automapper?rq=1