# How to map models at different layers in Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern

This is about Mapping Models in Generic Repository Pattern.

I have three layers in my solution

1. WebAPI Layer - APIModel
2. DAL Layer - DALModel
3. EF - EFModels

All layers are implementing Generics.

I am in dilemma that how do I pass models and map it other layer's model.

```
public class BaseController<Model> : ApiController
{
     // call to service
}  

public class BaseServices<Model>
{
    // call to dal repository
}

 public class BaseRepository<Model>
{
    // call to EF
}
```

**Problem/Questions**

**Scenario 1:**

I could expose all 3 models to all layers. i.e.: 
`public class BaseController<APIModel, DALModel, EFModel>`. But is this necessary? I don't wish to expose all models on all layers. I also don't wish to use EFModel as single model to be used everywhere.

**Scenario 2:**

I could pass only relevant model to each layer i.e.:

```
public class BaseController<APIModel>
public class BaseService<APIModel, DALModel>
public class BaseRepository<DALModel, EFModel>
```

If this is what should be done, where do I put mapping code? Which means how do I map `BaseService<APIModel, DALModel>` to `BaseRepository<DALModel, EFModel>`.  Can I have some sample code?

I have looked at some sample codes on internet, but couldn't find what I needed.

I can only think of these 2 scenarios, If someone can provide a better solution, I would be very thankful.

Comment: *But is this necessary?* That's all a question of opinion. Is the repository layer necessary, to begin with?

Comment: But if the models are exposed on all layers, whats the point of having different models.! Also are you suggesting Scenario 2 isn't possible or not recommended !!

Comment: There is a lot of well written code on this site that follows the ViewModel pattern with no repository (EF is a repository you know). You have entity models that are not exposed and viewmodels for specific use cases and tools like AutoMapper to reduce the friction. We've yet to run into the need for another layer above that. When we get new developers they can jump in pretty quickly and understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1: 100% incorrect.
Scenario 2: isn't good approach.

I think the below approach can be good.

```
    public class BaseController<TService,DTO> : ApiController
    {
        private readonly TService _service;
        public BaseController(TService iService){
            _service = iService;
        }
        public List<DTO> GetAll(){
            return _service.GetAll();
        }
    }  

    public class BaseServices<IRepository,DTO>
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repo;
        public BaseServices(IRepository iRepository){
            _repo = iRepository;
        }
        public List<DTO> GetAll(){
            return _repo.GetAll().ToDTOList<DTO>();
        }
    }

     public class BaseRepository<Model>
    {
        public List<Model> GetAll(){
            return DB.Set<Model>().ToList();
        }
    }



    public class HomeRepository():BaseRepository<Home>{}
    public class HomeService():BaseServices<IHomeService,HomeDTO>{}
    public class HomeController():BaseController<IHomeService,HomeDTO>{}



        public static class Extensions
        {
           public static List<DTO> ToDTOList<DTO>(this IEnumerable<Model> entityList)   where DTO : class {
                return Mapper.Map<DTO>(model);
           }
       }
```

Comment: Following above.. Let's say I have BaseService<SModel> class, where I need to call method of BaseRepository<RModel>, how do I put code to map SModel to RModel. I can't created object of BaseRepository<RModel> before mapping. Hope u get the problem

Comment: you could write an extension method and mapping model to DTO or vise versa.

Comment: Use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to mapping one object to another.

Comment: That I know buddy. What I need to know is where do I put that mapping code? can you provide sample? Should I do it like BaseRepositort<SModel.toRModel()> ??

Comment: checkout the [mapping-a-dto-to-an-entity-with-automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156437/mapping-a-dto-to-an-entity-with-automapper)

Comment: Put the mapper in the Service Layer.

Comment: @DheerajKumar: How to map two entities is a separate question and should be posted as such. For the current topic, you can rely on the existence of a `public A ConvertToA(B b)` (and vice versa) method. How to implement these methods is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Expose to the upper level the models you need for that upper level.

Instead of:

```
public class BaseService<APIModel, DALModel>
```

just do:

```
public class BaseService<APIModel>
```

Inside BaseService, you use Automapper to map from/to DALModel, so the users of the class BaseService don't need to know DALModel. This is abstraction and separation of concerns. You will be able to handle and modify in each layer your data transfer model without affecting the upper layers.