# I want to use Automapper in Business Layer of my ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, n-tier-architecture

I've created an ASP.NET MVC application with 3 layers (WebUi layer, Business Layer, Data Layer). I already have Automapper in the WebUi layer and it's working, I can map the model in WebUi to Dto in the business layer, but now I need Automapper in the Business Layer to map the Dto to entities.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Here is example to Map DTO back Entities.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156437/mapping-a-dto-to-an-entity-with-automapper

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had to install automappel in the solution and not in the Ui project