# How to automap the property with same class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I want to map all properties from `product` to `result`.

I use the route to pass the model, then follow the tutorial to map all properties.
But I want to make my code more flexible.
So I try both to direct pass `product` to `result` and use `AutoMapper`.
But either doesn’t work.
I have print `changeTracker`. When I use like `result.Name = product.Name;` ETC, it can track the change. But The method I try to use doesn’t work;

## Original

```
public IActionResult Edit(TempProducts product)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = (from s in _db.Product where s.ID == product.ID select s).FirstOrDefault();
        result.Name = product.Name;
        result.Description = product.Description;
        result.PublishDate = product.PublishDate;
        result.CategoryId = product.CategoryId;
        result.Price = product.Price;
        result.DefaultImageId = product.DefaultImageId;
        result.Quantity = product.Quantity;
        result.Status = product.Status;

        _db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        Console.WriteLine(_db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Pass2.index));
    }

    else
    {
        return View(product);
    }
}
```

## Direct pass

```
public IActionResult Edit(TempProducts product)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = (from s in _db.Product where s.ID == product.ID select s).FirstOrDefault();
        result = product;

        _db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        Console.WriteLine(_db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Pass2.index));
    }

    else
    {
        return View(product);
    }
}
```

## Use AutoMapper

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Edit(TempProducts product)
{
    if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
        {
            c.CreateMap<TempProducts, TempProducts>();
        });
        IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
#nullable disable
        var result = (from s in _db.Product where s.ID == product.ID select s).FirstOrDefault();
        result = mapper.Map<TempProducts,TempProducts>(product);

        _db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        Console.WriteLine(_db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Pass2.index));
    }

    else
    {
        return View(product);
    }
}
```

## Edit: TempProducts

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace forLearn.Models.RouteTest
{
    public partial class TempProducts
    {
        public uint ID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }=null!;

        public string Description { get; set; }=null!;

        [Range(0, 999)]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 999.99)]
        public int Price { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

        public bool Status { get; set; }

        public int DefaultImageId { get; set; }

        [Range(0, 999)]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both mechanisms replace the `result` with a new object reference, so it's no longer an EF object. Hence ChangeTracker is not detecting the changes.

Comment: Please tell me how to fix my code.

Comment: You can try this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156437/mapping-a-dto-to-an-entity-with-automapper. Also, can you share your `TempProducts` and the entity class? I just want to see what are the properties in both classes.

Comment: thank you, I know DTO, but I don’t want to use another class that has the same properties just for passing data.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
Just add this below the `result`.

```
_db.Entry(result).CurrentValues.SetValues(product);
```